# Nexus adds an ending / when using pip install

Tags: python, proxy, pip, nexus, pypi

I have a strange issue when using PyPI proxy on a private Nexus repository.

I explain:

I have set pip index as:
`nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-group/pypi`

And pip index-url as:
`nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-group/simple`

Ok. When i do for example 
pip install gitpython==3.0.4, it tries to fetch from this URL:
`nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-group/simple/gitpython/`

On which every gitpython version are shown, but each redirects towards
`nexus.example.com/packages/random_hash_to_my_dep` which of course doesn't exist (even going to the url with browser brings to a 404)

What i saw is that instead it should fetch from this URL:
`nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-group/simple/gitpython` (notice the missing ending /)

And this time, when browsing this URL, every version of gitpython are shown, but redirects towards 
`file.pythonhosted.com/packages/random_hash_to_my_dep` which this time downloads my dependencies.

The problem is that i don't know how to configure this, as i'm never asking Nexus to add an ending / to my URL using pip install my_dep.

Any clue on how to fix this?